# Proving that $S_{4}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{12}$

Tags: group-theory

> Question:Prove that $S_{4}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{12}$

This question seem trivial enough. But there is a subtle point that I feel isn't quite evident to me.

It is trivial to see that both groups have the same order.

Note that the elements in $D_{12}$ are {r,f} where r and f are rotation and flip functions respectively.
Evidently, by geometric inspection, the order of the element r=12 and the order of f=2.

Recall that the order of an element in $S_{4}$ is the LCM of the cycle length of the permutation. The elements of $S_{4}$ are all such permutations of the finite set $\omega$=${1,2,3,4}$.

Let $\alpha$ be an element in $S_{4}$. 
Then,$\alpha$ have possibly 1 cycle of length 4, 1 cycle of length 3 conjoin with 1 cycle of length 1, 2 cycle of length 2.
So, the order of $\alpha={4,3,2}$.

Given two distinct groups, exactly what more can be deduced in the case where the elements in each group do not have the same order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the groups were isomorphic then they would have the same number of elements of any given order. So you are done.

Comment: Hint: $S_4$ has no order 6 elements (can you see why?), $D_{12}$ does (can you see why?)

Comment: I can see that $S_{4}$ has no order 6 elements. This follows from the fact that the order of any element in $S_{4}$ is the LCM of the cycle lengths. But I cannot see why $D_{12}$ has an element of order 6.@JustinBenfield

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Does this follow from a theorem?

Comment: This follows from basic properties of isomorphisms (you should do this as an exercise).

Comment: Hint: $D_{12}$ is the symmetry group of the regular dodecagon (12-sided polygon), what happens if you take the group element that represents rotation by 2/12th turn and compose it with itself again and again?

Comment: @JustinBenfield This is now clear. $2/12^{th}$=1/6.
So, 6 rotation gives the identity. Hence, the order is 6.
In general, any order of 6n gives the identity for all integers n.

Comment: @Mathematicing: In general, if you have any element, $g$ in a group $G$ that is of order $n$, then there must also be elements of every order $k$ that divides $n$. This is because the (sub)-group generated by $g$, $<g>$ is a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Yes!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the center $Z(D_{12}) \neq 1$

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways are there to answer your question, but the answer you will expect will depend on what properties of these two groups you are familiar with. It would be worth for you to *prove* these properties, to clarify the answer.

In dihedral groups, at least half elements are of order $2$; it contains an element of order equal to half the order of group; its center has order $2$ when its order is divisible by $4$, and many more properties are there. 
You can see that, $S_4$ violates all these three properties.